# Android WebView inside ViewPager displays only after click

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I've stumbled upon another tricky error...

I'm using basic ViewPager, which consists of several pages, which are basically consisted of HTML, displayed by a WebView.

I use the method:

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank")
```

for showing the contents. HTML is a String variable. Everything work fine, but I would expect all the views to be preloaded (I've set offscreenpage limit of the viewpager and even instantiate item is called right with the right data), but it isn't.

The webview is loaded, but displayed only after the click. It doesn't occur to me first, because I clicked everytime I wanted to show another page, but if you move to quickly, clicks get a bit delayed and no page is displayed. Only after I click again.
Or, if I drag one page and move slightly right, I can see that the another view is not loaded yet... it displays only after one second.

Has anybody encountered something similar?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and am looking for help, too. It seems that the entire ViewPager doesn't show up until it has focused after the click, but none of the requestFocus() nor requestChildFocus() did work.
One little different thing, the problem only happens to me when the ViewPager is initialized. When I moved to another page, the webview content displayed well.

Comment: Yes, I'm experiencing the same issue... I also tried, whether there is problem with loadDataWithBaseURL, but it doesn't matter. loadData, loadDataWithBaseURL and loadPage, all of them behave the same in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this: just simply use the `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(position)` to display the page that you want as default (normally the first page in my case).

Comment: I'm setting the current item. Doesn't help though, or I didn't understand. But anyway, I tried to modify my loadDataWithBaseURL and it seems to be working now...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `setPageTransformer` in pager. I have same problem and I fixed it.